# How I get the number of (currently) established TCP connections in prometheus (kubernetes monitoring)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using this command in linux  to see (currently) established TCP connections:

```
netstat -ant | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

How can i translate this command to PromQL (per node)  ?

I am using prometheus with node exporter in my kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get number of currently open TCP connections, you can use `node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab` (Gauge) metric.

you can also use `node_netstat_Tcp_ActiveOpens` (Counter) metrics with appropriate rate such as

`rate(node_netstat_Tcp_ActiveOpens[10m])`

These metrics are based on [TCP-MIB (RFC-4022)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4022) and they are obtained by parsing `/proc/net/netstat` and `/proc/net/tcp` files on every node running exporter.

Comment: Thanks, Can i also use 
 /proc/net/sockstat and /proc/net/sockstat to get 
established connections (inuse), connections in a time wait state (tw) 
and total tcp connections (alloc) ?

Comment: @karlos yes, just find out metrics name based on mentioned MIB

Comment: i have a pb where node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab in prometheus give only 2
but when i do netstat -ant | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l, i am getting 3000. 
any idea ?

Comment: well, that's general problem with `Gauge` metrics such as `node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab`. You will get only value that Prometheus asked for (usually every 30sec). So that's exact situation where counter metric (such as `node_netstat_Tcp_ActiveOpens`) comes handy. If you plot it in graph, you will got increase over time and don't  miss moment where process opened bunch of connections just after scrape of metric was done

Comment: I Did  this post for this pb with the graph from grafana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819667/node-exporter-node-sockstat-tcp-alloc-not-coherent-with-node-netstat-tcp-currest