# node exporter node_sockstat_TCP_alloc not coherent with node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using  [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) with kubernetes and prometheus to moniter the number of current tcp connections

From  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806122/how-i-get-the-number-of-currently-established-tcp-connections-in-prometheus-k/68806355#68806355) i found that node_sockstat_TCP_alloc or node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab metric can be used for such thing.

I started doing tcp connection using mosquito connect and pub.

The node_sockstat_TCP_alloc increased as the number of mqtt user increase

[image]

But node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab is always constant

[image]