# Monitoring server socket per state and socket using Prometheus

Tags: socket.io, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806122/how-i-get-the-number-of-currently-established-tcp-connections-in-prometheus-k) but goes a bit further. I'd like to monitor the number of sockets in a specific state for a specific port using Prometheus exporter. For example I'd like to monitor the number of sockets in ESTABLISHED state to my Oracle Database listening on port 1521.

Currently I'm using a simple shell script which does basically a `netstat -tan | grep ESTABLISHED | grep ':1521' | wc-l` and I'm wondering if I could replace that with some data from the Prometheus node exporter?